# Convert yaml file to json

Tags: c#, json, yaml, yamldotnet

I'm trying to convert a yaml file to a json file with a C# application. 
My application crashed on the following row 
`"created: !ruby/object:ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone"`

How can I convert the date, because I need this part: "2016-10-14 04:56:51.057147000 Z"

The yaml:

```
- id: 1
  created: !ruby/object:ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
    utc: &4 2016-10-14 04:56:51.057147000 Z
    zone: *2
    time: *4
```

Code:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using YamlDotNet.Serialization;     

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var r = new StringReader(@"
- id: 1
  created: !ruby/object:ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
    utc: &4 2016-10-14 04:56:51.057147000 Z
    zone: *2
    time: *4
"); 
        var deserializer = new Deserializer();
        var yamlObject = deserializer.Deserialize(r);

        var serializer = new Serializer(SerializationOptions.JsonCompatible);
        serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, yamlObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: To serialize a Date, you need a *date* to begin with. The contents of the `utc` property aren't a date. This is a string that kind-of-looks-like-a-date but has a weird `&4 ` prefix, and a suffix ` Z` that could be a timezone with an extra whitespace, could be something else. This can only be treated as a string

Comment: You have to write a representer for this ruby tag: `!ruby/object:ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` so you get an object that extracts the  the date from the value for `utc`. For that you don't need the time part. Alternatively bind the  ruby intepreter into your C# program and have ruby load the yaml, then pick up the date value.